# Can't find a random character in Maisonette 9

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I'm playing *[The Ballad Of Gay Tony](http://www.rockstargames.com/theballadofgaytony)* and I've completed all of the main story missions. However, there's a random "female" icon on the map in (or very, very close to) Maisonette 9.

I've been inside, out, on the first floor (above the bar) and even on top of the building and at various times as well and I can't seem to find the character. Google search claimed that I had to go into the bar at 9 sharp and have a shot - which I did but I am still missing the character.

Is there any planetary alignment I need to be aware of in order to start this random character mission, please?

Comment: Have a look in the manager's office... Unless I'm thinking of the wrong club (likely).

Answer (score 1):

I can't be completely sure which mission the icon is referring to, but as @Beeblebrox said, it might be pointing to Joni inside the security room at Maisonette 9.